Snyk test fails when executed via Jenkins
We are getting the following error when running the Jenkins job to test our React Native code base for vulnerabilities.
Snyk installation is UP-TO-DATE
Testing for known issues...
> /Users/appbuilder/Work/CICDSetup/tools/io.snyk.jenkins.tools.SnykInstallation/Snyk/node_modules/.bin/snyk test --json --severity-threshold=medium --org=PSoft --project-name=Mob-Service
FATAL: Snyk command execution failed
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'env': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"env: node: No such file or directory
"; line: 1, column: 4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:722)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2868)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1914)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:773)
    at io.snyk.jenkins.model.ObjectMapperHelper.unmarshallTestResult(ObjectMapperHelper.java:54)
    at io.snyk.jenkins.SnykStepBuilder.perform(SnykStepBuilder.java:262)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:803)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:197)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:513)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1907)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Invoke Snyk Security task' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Snyk Security task' marked build as failure

Running the same command at a shell from the same folder works fine. The issue arises only when it initiated via the "snyk security task" build action.

We tried different things without any success

Got a fresh checkout of the code
Wiping our the workspace altogether
Restricted the scan of files to only package.json or ios/podfile
Create a brand new Jenkins project and try

Now we are running out of options. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Just a side comment: sure that this "--org=PSoft" is the right org? Cause in most cases the org slugs are lowercase, and make sure you don't put the org display name but the org slug, or org id. But that's probably not related to the issue you have, just a side comment.

@MathiasConradt I was using the org slug. It is with an uppercase letter. Thanks anyway.
